# Scrolling in Visual Studio 2008 solution explorer is slow

Tags: visual-studio-2008

If I expand a project in the solution explorer of Visual Studio 2008 and scroll through its content with PgUp/Down, it behaves like e.g. Internet Explorer with "optimized scrolling" enabled (I only have a german version installed, I don't know the real english option).

Is it possible to disable this behaviour? It really slows down the scrolling.